# How to pass a value in a form action in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a view that list all objects in a database and for each object creates a form for saving to a different table. My problem is, that the value isn't being passed to my function.

Here is my blade.php file:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Items') }}</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">
                    @foreach($items as $item)
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="card">
                                <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">{{ $item->name }}</h5>
                                    <p class="card-text">$ {{ $item->price }}</p>
                                    @auth
                                    <form method="post" action="{{ route('carts.store', $item) }}"> 
                                        @csrf
                                        @method('post')
                                        <button type="submit" class="form-control btn">add to cart</button>
                                    </form>
                                    @endauth

                                    <form method="post" action="{{ route('item.destroy', $item) }}"> 
                                        @csrf
                                        @method('delete')
                                        <button type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-danger">delete</button>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

and my function in the CartsController:

```
public function store(Item $item)
{
    $cart = new Cart();
    $cart->user_id = auth()->id();
    $cart->item_id = $item->id;
    
    $cart->save();

    return redirect('/item');
}
```

When I click on add to cart I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'item_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `carts` (`user_id`, `item_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, ?, 2020-08-24 07:35:44, 2020-08-24 07:35:44))

I've tried passing the id to the function directly but that also doesn't seem to work. I'm very confused as to why this is happening since I can use `$item` two rows earlier without a problem.

Comment: Are you using implicit or explicit route model binding?

Comment: implicit I think. I'm still very new to php and laravel

Comment: You suppose to pass the `$item->id` as in `action="{{ route('carts.store', $item->id ) }}"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided that your route model binding is setup correctly, it won't actually matter whether you pass the `id` of an object or the object itself to the the `route()` function.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#implicit-binding

When you run `php artisan route:list`, you should see something similar to this:

```
POST | cart/store/item/{item} | carts.store | App\Http\Controllers\CartController@store
```

> Laravel automatically resolves Eloquent models defined in routes or controller actions whose type-hinted variable names match a route segment name.

So any of the following will actually work

```
{{ route('carts.store', $item) }}
```

OR

```
{{ route('carts.store', $item->id) }}
```

OR

```
{{ route('carts.store', ['item' =>  $item->id]) }}
```

Should all resolve to the same thing.

---

**Addendum**

So the route you are using doesn't have a route parameter for your item (i.e `{item}`), as such it won't know which `Item` object you are referencing.

You can either:

1. Amend your route to include this route parameter

OR

2. use the `Request` object to resolve the `Item` instead.

**Blade**

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('carts.store') }}"> 
    @csrf
    @method('post')
    <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="{{ $item->id }}">
    <button type="submit" class="form-control btn">add to cart</button>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $cart = new Cart();
    $cart->user_id = auth()->id();
    $cart->item_id = $request->item_id;
    
    $cart->save();

    return redirect('/item');
}
```

Comment: `php artisan routes:list` returns this
`POST | carts | carts.store | App\Http\Controllers\CartsController@store | web`
The `$fillable` array is also set up correctly. But it's still not working

Comment: See the addendum to my answer with an explaination of what's going on